# Using the limit Definition, compute $\frac{\text d}{\text dx}f(x)$ for $f(x) = x-\frac{3}{x}$

Tags: calculus

I got totally lost in this part of the test. Can someone give me some guidance? How do you calculate the answer? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is a little difficult to follow, but it looks to me like your mistake was algebra. The limit you set up was $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)-\frac{3}{x+h}\left(-x-\frac{3}{x}\right)}{h}$$ which is incorrect. It should be $$\begin{align}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)-\frac{3}{x+h}-\left(x-\frac{3}{x}\right)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x+h-\frac{3}{x+h}-x+\frac{3}{x}}{h} \\ = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h-\frac{3}{x+h}+\frac{3}{x}}{h} \\ = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h\frac{x(x+h)}{x(x+h)}-\frac{3x}{x(x+h)}+\frac{3(x+h)}{x(x+h)}}{h} \\ = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{hx^2+xh^2+3h}{x(x+h)}}{h} \\ = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x^2+xh+3}{x(x+h)} \end{align}$$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

I will only show the $\dfrac{3}{x}$ part.

For $h \neq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\dfrac{3}{x+h} - \dfrac{3}{x}}{h} &= \dfrac{\dfrac{3x - 3(x+h)}{x(x+h)}}{h} \\
&= \dfrac{\dfrac{-3h}{x(x+h)}}{h} \\
&= -\dfrac{3h}{hx(x+h)} \\
&= - \dfrac{3}{x^2 + hx}
\end{align*}
And hence it follows that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{3}{x+h} - \dfrac{3}{x}}{h} =\lim_{h \to 0}- \dfrac{3}{x^2 + hx} = -\dfrac{3}{x^2}
\end{equation*}

Comment: How did you get negative 3/x^2

Comment: @Cetshwayo I differentiated the function $f=3/x$ instead of $f=-3/x$. Hence the different signs of the derivative.